# SWT Shell setRegion is not working in Eclipse splash in macOS

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a strange issue with the eclipse splash plugin I have developed. Its a non rectangular window and I used `shell.setRegion ()` to define the polygon.

This is perfectly working on Windows machines, but showing blank screen in macOS High Sierra.

Here is the minified version which reduced to just few lines which really affects.

It is showing a simple triangle as the splash screen while eclipse launch.

[image]

**plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.splashHandlers">
  <splashHandler
        class="CustomSplash2"
        id="splashHandler">
  </splashHandler>
  <splashHandlerProductBinding
        productId="org.eclipse.platform.ide"
        splashId="splashHandler">
  </splashHandlerProductBinding>
</extension>
</plugin>
```

**SplashHandler**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.splash.BasicSplashHandler;

public class CustomSplash2 extends BasicSplashHandler {

public CustomSplash2() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void init(final Shell splash) {
        super.init(splash);
        FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
        splash.setLayout(layout);
        Region region = new Region();
        region.add(new int[] { 0, 200, 100, 0, 200, 200 });
        splash.setRegion(region);
        splash.setSize(region.getBounds().width, region.getBounds().height);
    }
}
```

eclipse version :  Neon.3

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a problem in the macOS version of `Shell` which doesn't draw the background image if a region is set and a background color is not set.

Just setting the `Shell` background color seems to work around this issue and makes the image appear.

```
splash.setBackground(splash.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
```

The issue is in the `Shell.drawBackground` method